# Dataframe groupby when specific values are encountered on a given row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe and I would like to group(or slice)it. The dataframe is in a form of

```
A  B  C
a  b  1
a  b  0
a  b  1
a  b  2
a  b  0
a  e  3
a  e  3
f  g  6
f  g  7
f  g  0
```

I would like to first group the dataframe on column A and B. Then,each group is further split by a certain value into smaller groups with consecutive rows. For example,after grouping the dataframe by columns A and B,I would like to refine the grouping on the third level each time I encounter a `0` in column `C`. So the grouped dataframe is like

```
A  B  C
a  b  1
a  b  0

a  b  1
a  b  2
a  b  0

a  e  3
a  e  3

f  g  6
f  g  7
f  g  0
```

Grouping a dataframe by column values like columns A and B in the example is simple but I dont know how to further group on level 3 into consecutive rows with certain cut points.  Thank you in advance if you could help.

Comment: bud, your question does not make sense. what do you mean by further divided by a certain value? divide de groups by 0 means nothing

Comment: English issue, here divide actually means *cut* , *split* or *partition* , see below

Comment: @Noobie see anwser and corrected OP

Answer (score 1):

To do so the approach is alway the same: create an extra column (or several sometimes) that represents your specific grouping logic, then group against it:

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'cut_point']).groups
Out[139]: 
{('a', 'b', 0.0): Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64'),
 ('a', 'b', 1.0): Int64Index([2, 3, 4], dtype='int64'),
 ('a', 'e', 2.0): Int64Index([5, 6], dtype='int64'),
 ('f', 'g', 2.0): Int64Index([7, 8, 9], dtype='int64')}

df['cut_point'] = (df.C==0).cumsum().shift().fillna(0)

df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'cut_point']).groups
Out[141]: 
{('a', 'b', 0.0): Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64'),
 ('a', 'b', 1.0): Int64Index([2, 3, 4], dtype='int64'),
 ('a', 'e', 2.0): Int64Index([5, 6], dtype='int64'),
 ('f', 'g', 2.0): Int64Index([7, 8, 9], dtype='int64')}
```

Comment: the answer works for my issue. Thank you very much for the approach particularly it could be generalized in many other problems.